How to deal with "cans of worms" of references in publications
I have found an algorithm that solved a puzzle in an unexpected way, so I'm planning to publish it on arXiv.
After some online research I learned that the puzzle belongs to a larger class of more or less related problems with a long list of relevant publications that should probably be cited as references to prior art.
Question:

is it acceptable for a serious mathematical paper to provide the circumstances of the discovery of an algorithm as an explanation for not going into details of prior art but rather focus on the algorithm and its properties?


Maybe you can find one or more good review papers that you can cite, mentioning that more references are given there?

When I read the title, I expected it to be about papers/areas that have lots of issues/controversies.

I don't understand how the circumstances you detail in your post (basically, "I solved a problem X without realizing at first that it belongs to a class of problems Y") provide an explanation for not going into details of prior work. I mean, it does convey to the reader that you chose not to bother to look much into prior work, but is that really what you want the reader to take away from your explanation?

You need to know whether your algorithm is novel. For that, you need an overview of the field. That overview goes into the introduction.

Help your reader to understand the context of this problem/algorithm
Academic articles are expected to be placed in their relevant context through a literature review and citation of relevant works.  This is to aid a reader to ensure that they are given a broad understanding of the field and the corresponding ability to look up relevant materials that frame the subject under discussion in the paper.  It also assists the reader to understand what is (and is not) novel in your paper and how it contributes to the broader literature in the field.
While it is perfectly acceptable to provide the circumstances of discovery of an algorithm, this does not alleviate the need to tell your reader about other relevant works relating to that problem or a larger class of problems that subsumes it.  If that latter information is useful context then it should be included in your paper to give your reader a broad understanding of the field in which your algorithm falls.
As to the problem of opening a "can of worms" in your literature review, this requires some judgment in relation to relevance and also some judicious consideration of how "deep" to go.  It sounds like you have identified a large body of literature for a larger class of problem that subsumes your problem.  Whether all of this "should be cited" depends on how relevant it is to your more narrow problem and algorithm.  It might be reasonable to cite some core papers about the larger class of problem without going too "deep" into that larger field.  Think carefully about what is useful to your reader.

I like your well-balanced and neutral discussion of the subject

I'm famous for my well-balanced and neutral discussion on this site.  


is it acceptable for a serious mathematical paper to provide the circumstances of the discovery of an algorithm as an explanation for not going into details of prior art but rather focus on the algorithm and its properties?

Short answer:
No,
you should make reasonable efforts to discuss your work's connections to relevant literature. (But you are not required to open and fully digest any can of worms you encounter.)

Detailed answer:
No one cares about the "circumstances of the discovery" that you are writing about. That would be seen as irrelevant, and providing those circumstances as an explanation for anything would, in my opinion, detract from whatever seriousness your paper purports to have. (To be clear, if the circumstances are interesting you can mention them just for a bit of extra color, but they do not justify writing the paper in any other way than you would be writing under different circumstances.)
The main thing that determines whether a paper is serious or not is whether it makes a valuable contribution to human knowledge.
Other factors that affect the perception of seriousness is whether the author seems to have done a thorough job of addressing the issues arising from the topic being discussed, and issues adjacent to them.
Not citing relevant literature that you could easily cite, and not discussing related or adjacent issues that you could easily discuss, are all signs - and unfortunately, not uncommon ones - of an author who is trying to finish a paper quickly with minimal work and without doing a serious job of studying the implications of their work to what already exists in the literature. The general impression this leaves is of a sloppy, unserious author and paper. Even when the research contribution itself is nice, this can leave readers with a poor taste. It is in essence a missed opportunity to pick some low-hanging fruit that makes your paper better and increases its potential impact with a small investment of effort.
So, as a general rule I would say, do not leave low-hanging fruit on the tree. If your work relates to topics that you can, with relatively low effort, understand and discuss at least briefly in your paper - even a paragraph or a sentence along with a citation can provide a valuable service to interested readers - and if you want to be perceived by others as a serious scholar, then you should feel obligated to invest that effort.
Now, what about high-hanging fruit? Mathematical research topics are so complex and interwoven with deep connections that it can indeed happen sometimes that you may need to make a very large effort to understand the full implications of your discovery on the field it relates to. (I know the feeling, this has happened to me many times.) In that case, it's fine if you don't make that effort; no one expects you to open these sorts of large cans of worms when all you want to do is discuss an algorithm related to a puzzle that interests you. In that case, the appropriate thing to do would be to at least tell the readers that your work has possible connections to a large body of literature, a full discussion of which lies beyond the scope of your paper, and give some relevant citations (for example to some survey papers, or other papers that serve as good entry points to that literature). Doing this would only require a small amount of effort, and would reassure readers knowledgeable about these connections that you are not trying to get away with a sloppy or unserious attitude to scholarly research by hiding relevant literature you are aware of. And it gives all readers the information they need to open the can of worms themselves if they should desire to do so.
If you take this approach, the impact of your paper may be limited by the fact that you're only discussing a special case of some much larger theory, but I think a paper doing this can still call itself a serious paper that makes a useful contribution other people will respect and appreciate. And if your result is interesting enough, other people will surely come along later and work on mining your ideas to pick the higher-hanging fruit those ideas point to.

I'm a civilian but the only time I recall the circumstances of discovery being relevant was some proof discovery that everyone thought was new and interesting and then at the last second before publication it was rediscovered in some ultra obscure paper decades earlier.  And finding that was interesting and why it had zero impact previously was interesting.

I would disagree with the "no one cares" generalization; it may be the mindset of some to not care about the origin of a problem that led to a new contribution to scientific research; other may see it as a source of inspiration for identifying interesting research topics.

@ManfredWeis to clarify, what I meant was "no one cares, in the context of the question of whether your paper should be accepted to a journal (or should be considered a 'serious' paper)". Like I said, it may be an interesting story people would enjoy reading about, so in that sense I agree with you people might "care" about it. But as an explanation for why your paper is written the way it is or why it omits discussion of certain things, it is irrelevant.

One option is to cite the latest review or text on the subject and add "and reference therein", thus inviting the reader to follow up, if they want to know more on the subject.
Note that the above recommendation reflects my philosophy that the references should help understand and justify the premises of the research. However, often they also serve (perhaps unavoidably) to please/reassure those who have made contributions to the subject - here one could limit oneself to citing "the big shots" and anyone who bothers to complain that they were not properly cited (this is why many authors choose to let their paper hang for a couple of weeks on arxive or another online resource, so that people may voice their objections.)

Why omit it?
I guess, listing all relevant publications is a lot of work on the part of the author, so I kind of understand the motivation.
I have no experience with arxiv, but it does not appear that they impose any limits in terms of paper length, in contrast to other publications which might impose a page limit or something similar.
So, if there is no strict limit on the paper, there is very little speaking against including the "can of worms" into the paper. Apart from the additional work.
If you are worried, that discussing all the related problems might take too much space and disturb the structure of the paper, you might consider moving this part into an appendix. This way you preserve the conciseness of your paper, without omitting the discussion of related literature and related problems.

I think "apart from the additional work" is really the issue OP is worried about. It can sometimes take an unreasonable amount of work to understand the full literature related to your result, so it's a legitimate question what is the best way for an author to handle this situation. If it's a small amount of effort, then sure, the author should do that extra work and include the discussion.

Personally, I think it is acceptable, or rather, that it should be more acceptable than it currently is. Nobody has time to be an expert in everything, and if you found something novel by being outside the field that should be seen as something positive. I would personally be quite happy to read a paper that says, in effect, "we skip a detailed literature review of field A because our background is in field B; see XYZ for a review of A." Giving the broader context of the problem within field A is still important though, as other answers have said.
What's important is not to claim the algorithm is new if you think it might already exist. That might take some work to check, either by following the rabbit hole of references or by consulting with an expert. If it does already exist you can always present your paper as an expository one, presenting a new perspective on existing work.

It is also my gut feeling that nowadays a few keywords and citations should suffice to raise the attention of experts in the field so they can check the relevance of publication; of course an extensive online search for already existing prior work is inevitable but I don't see why every paper should list the whole blockchain of a problem's history.

Of course no one can be an expert in everything! But if you just want to talk about something that may or may not be a new piece of human knowledge without doing the legwork of carefully checking and explaining why it is a new piece of knowledge then an academic publication or preprint server are not the correct venue. You can always write a blog or send the results to friends or mathematicians who might be interested!

@user2705196 I don't think the question is about checking whether it's already known, and you'll note that my answer says you still have to do that. I'm just saying you don't need to include a detailed literature review in the paper if you're not an expert in the field. Why would the reader want to read a review by a non-expert anyway?
